# How to disable minimum value of 0 in Slider?

Tags: ios, swiftui, watchkit

I'm working on a watchOS 7 app that uses Slider in SwiftUI. My goal is to allow selection for values `1.0`, `2.0`, and `3.0`. When `sliderValues` is `1.0`, pressing minus button should not change `sliderValue` to `0.0`. How can I disallow selection of value `0.0`? Here is a picture to better illustrate the goal:

[image]

View file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sliderValue: Double = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0...3, step: 1)
            Text("\(sliderValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `1...3` for the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the range to `1...3`. This does make the UI only show 0, 1, or 2 segments.

If you like the look of having 3 segments in the UI, then
you can watch the value change with `onChange(of:)` and set it back to `1` if it goes below `1`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sliderValue: Double = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0...3, step: 1)
            .onChange(of: sliderValue) { value in
                if value < 1 {
                    sliderValue = 1
                }
            }
            Text("\(sliderValue)")
        }
    }
}
```